# ValueError: Negative dimension size caused by subtracting 2 from 1 for for '{{node max_pooling2d_16/MaxPool}}

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, semantic-segmentation

I have a multiclass U-Net model which i use it for multiclass segmentation approach, when i use this model i am encountering error

> ValueError: Negative dimension size caused by subtracting 2 from 1 for '{{node max_pooling2d_16/MaxPool}} = MaxPoolT=DT_FLOAT, data_format="NCHW", explicit_paddings=[], ksize=[1, 1, 2, 2], padding="VALID", strides=[1, 1, 2, 2]' with input shapes: [?,16,139,1].

where is the mistake in defining the model?

Multiclass model code:

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, UpSampling2D, concatenate, Conv2DTranspose, BatchNormalization, Dropout, Lambda


def multi_unet_model(n_classes=4, IMG_HEIGHT=139, IMG_WIDTH=139, IMG_CHANNELS=1):
#Build the model
    inputs = Input((IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH, IMG_CHANNELS))
    #s = Lambda(lambda x: x / 255)(inputs)   #No need for this if we normalize our inputs beforehand
    s = inputs

    #Contraction path
    c1 = Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same')(s)
    c1 = Dropout(0.1)(c1)
    c1 = Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same')(c1)
    p1 = MaxPooling2D((2, 2))(c1)
    
    c2 = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same')(p1)
    c2 = Dropout(0.1)(c2)
    c2 = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same')(c2)
    p2 = MaxPooling2D((2, 2))(c2)
     
    c3 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same')(p2)
    c3 = Dropout(0.2)(c3)
    c3 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same')(c3)
    p3 = MaxPooling2D((2, 2))(c3)
     
    c4 = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same')(p3)
    c4 = Dropout(0.2)(c4)
    c4 = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same')(c4)
    p4 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(c4)
     
    c5 = Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same')(p4)
    c5 = Dropout(0.3)(c5)
    c5 = Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same')(c5)
    
    #Expansive path 
    u6 = Conv2DTranspose(128, (2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='same')(c5)
    u6 = concatenate([u6, c4])
    c6 = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same')(u6)
    c6 = Dropout(0.2)(c6)
    c6 = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same')(c6)
     
    u7 = Conv2DTranspose(64, (2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='same')(c6)
    u7 = concatenate([u7, c3])
    c7 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same')(u7)
    c7 = Dropout(0.2)(c7)
    c7 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same')(c7)
     
    u8 = Conv2DTranspose(32, (2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='same')(c7)
    u8 = concatenate([u8, c2])
    c8 = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same')(u8)
    c8 = Dropout(0.1)(c8)
    c8 = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same')(c8)
     
    u9 = Conv2DTranspose(16, (2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='same')(c8)
    u9 = concatenate([u9, c1], axis=3)
    c9 = Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same')(u9)
    c9 = Dropout(0.1)(c9)
    c9 = Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same')(c9)
     
    outputs = Conv2D(n_classes, (1, 1), activation='softmax')(c9)
     
    model = Model(inputs=[inputs], outputs=[outputs])       

    return model
```

Defining the model

```
from sklearn.utils import class_weight
from tensorflow.keras import backend as K
K.set_image_data_format('channels_first')
class_weights = class_weight.compute_sample_weight('balanced', y_train)

def get_model():
        return multi_unet_model(n_classes=4, IMG_HEIGHT=IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH=IMG_WIDTH, IMG_CHANNELS=IMG_CHANNELS)
    
model = get_model()
```

Comment: what are IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH, IMG_CHANNELS when you call the model?

Comment: IMG_Height = 139 and img_width= 139 and IMG_Channels = 1

Comment: This dimensionality generates this error: A `Concatenate` layer requires inputs with matching shapes except for the concat axis. Got inputs shapes: [(None, 16, 16, 128), (None, 17, 17, 128)]

Comment: Considering this... are you able to resize your input images to an optimal size? (224, 224, 1) should be ok for your net without changing anything